# sencha touch: I could not theme Sencha Touch / ExtJS application

Tags: extjs4.2, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-theming, sencha-touch-2.3

I am developing a sencha touch application using sencha architect. I have to change the background color, font color, font-family and icons according my company's standard in the app.

I tried to create SASS file

`@import 'sencha-touch/base';
@import 'sencha-touch/base/all';
$myapp-font-family:"Arial";
$myapp-gray:'#707070';
.x-body{
    font-family:$myapp-font-family;
    background-color:myapp-gray;
}
.x-panel{
    background-color:$myapp-gray;
}`

It is not working / reflecting.

Question: how can we theme application. How can we use sass and css altogether in the app. I would like to know the same for ExtJS also.

--Sridhar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already using Sencha Architect, theming is built right in if you're using the latest version. See [this post](http://www.sencha.com/blog/re-skinning-your-apps-just-got-easier-with-sencha-architect-3) from the Sencha blog.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, we have default themes in Sencha Architect like DefaultTheme, BlackBerry, MountainView. I would like to create theme like default themes with respect to my company standards, which will be used in all my sencha app. Is this possible?

Comment: Right click on your theme and hit "export to file" which creates an XDC file. Then you can select EDIT > IMPORT COMPONENT and import that XDC file in other projects.

Answer (score 0):

In sencha touch you have to use the command **sencha app build** for compiling the sass files.
For style editing you can also use **sencha app watch**, in this way sencha cmd line tool will listent for changes in your sass files and automatically rebuilds your project.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used sencha architect.

But if its about using sass and css for theming sencha application than this [article](http://moduscreate.com/bootstrapping-and-theming-your-app-with-sencha-touch-2-2-0/) from moduscreate will really be helpful for a start.